# how to get uglifyjs to remove console.log statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, uglifyjs

For some reason even though I am compressing my js code with uglifyjs and supplying the `drop_console` arg, I still can't get it to remove the logs. Thoughts?

This is an npm script in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-js": "browserify ./lib/js/main.js --standalone myapp | uglifyjs --compress drop_console - > ./lib/dist/js/main.js"
  }
```

Comment: It works fine for me